# Poisson Spot vs. Shadows

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves

In textbooks, whenever I read about the Poisson spot, it involves a disk, and having light waves diffract around it and interfere constructively in the center. At the same time, when I read about shadows caused by light from extended sources, the light is sometimes aimed at similar disks, causing a circular penumbra and umbra. Why is is that sometimes shining light at a disk causes a Poisson spot and sometimes simply causes fuzzy shadows?

That is to say, why is this

[image]

different from this?

[image]

Comment: The difference is called coherence. The light from an extended thermal source like the incandescent lamp shown in the picture is neither spatially nor temporally coherent. In this case it's the missing spatial coherence that matters. You can try the experiment yourself. To produce a spatially coherent light source you can cover a torch light with aluminum foil in which you poke a small hole with a needle. Now destroy the spatial coherence by poking several holes at once all across the foil and see how the shadow and the bright spot get smeared out.

Comment: So any light from a point source, which does not produce a penumbra, will produce a bright spot in the center?

Comment: Any won't, but the ones that satisfy the condition named here will, it seems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arago_spot. I have never done the experiment myself and I have not seen it performed, as far as I can remember. It's basically a footnote of science history, even though it may be quite impressive if done right. It sounds like a fun thing to set one up and it can be done with few utensils at home. I hope you give it a try and that it turns out impressive!